# Conditionally default values relative to a few columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, default-value

I have a database which has a few tables, and one of them is user tables.

There are user ID, Authority Level, and Authority Activation columns, etc. in my user tables.

- If user id is 1, the authority level will be admin, and activation will be 1.
- If user id is not 1, it will be editor or author.
- If authority level is editor, activation will be 0.
- If authority level is author activation will be 1.

I handled all conditions except admin selection according to user id. How can I add this condition on my database? (Note: I'm using MSSQL)

Comment: Considering that the `UserID` is going to be unique, and it's the first ID, then seems like logic for the process you created that creates the initial user not for a `DEFAULT CONSTRAINT`.

Comment: You may create a trigger, which will modify inserted data as you wish

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion would be a stored procedure like the one below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insertTableRecord(
  Id INT, Authority_Level VARCHAR(20), Authority_Activation INT)
AS
BEGIN
  IF (@Id = 1)
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO myTable ([Id], [Authority Level], [Authority Activation])
    SELECT (@Id, @Authority_Level, 1)
  END
  IF (@Id = 2)
  BEGIN
    IF (@Authority_Level = 'Editor')
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO myTable ([Id], [Authority Level], [Authority Activation])
        SELECT (@Id, @Authority_Level, 0)
    END
    IF (@Authority_Level = 'Author')
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO myTable ([Id], [Authority Level], [Authority Activation])
        SELECT (@Id, @Authority_Level, 1)
    END
  END
END
```

You can customize the insertion logic here.
An INSERT trigger is also an alternative but not sure if you can populate columns before the insert completes from the INSERTED temporary table.
A default constraint is also an option as long as your table business logic does not change later.